Is it possible to make sand from bones? Would it have the same properties as regular sand?
Context: In a magic city, artificers use various types of sand as components for their magitek contraptions.
I like the idea of having one type of sand made out of the bones of magical creatures and its true composition being a big secret, but I am not sure it would work.
Question: Would bone-sand behave like regular sand?
Would it be fluid enough to flow in copper tubes and to be used in an hourglass? Or would it clump too much? Would its grains be the same size as beach sand? Could it be reused a bunch of times? Would it be smelly?

We have a strict one question per post policy. This includes bonus questions. We also do not answer subjective questions where we speculate how a reader will respond to stories written in your world.. I've edited this to ask a single question for you.

@sphennings It seems you have also deleted parts of the main question. Is there a way to put them back ? The extra questions about the smell and size of the bone-sand grains were there to clarify what kind of answer I am looking for

Behave like regular sand in which application? Filling bags for flood containment or mixing it with concrete cannot be compared.

Normally, the bones would be cremated before being ground into sand. Cremated bone is purely mineral, as all the organic substances burn out. Grain size would be finer or coarser, depending on how fine or how coarse it is ground.

@L.Dutch The application would be the construction of magic-fuelled machines. The sand would flow between different parts of the machine inside various tubes, or be stored in external hourglasses

@AlexP Aren't cremated bones more like ashes ? I'm not sure ashes are heavy enough to flow down inside an hourglass

@BabikaBabaka: They go through a grinder to make them look like ashes. You don't have to grind them so fne.

So, the physical application you're after is equivalent to sand running through an hour glass, just grind to appropriate grain size and you'll get that.

"Sand is a granular material composed of finely divided mineral particles. Sand has various compositions but is defined by its grain size." -Wikipedia (emphasis mine)

Bonemeal has a consistency between loam and sawdust.
Bone is a fibrous composite made of equal volumes of hydroxyapatite and proteins (mostly collagens and osteocalcin). When you grind it down, it breaks up into a porous, fibrous material more similar to sawdust than sand.  The fibers give it an airy, squishy, and slightly sticky consistency, even after you've fully dried it.
Another key feature of bone meal is that it will break up into particles of many different sizes.  Some will be large like sand particles and others will be microscopic like clay particles.  In this way, it will behave more like loam than sand.  So it absorbs water very well and becomes muddy instead of letting water just flow through it like sand.
... but it can be made more sand like with extra steps
After your grind and dry your bone, you will need to wash your bonemeal on a screen to get rid of the microscopic particles that will keep it loamy. Then you will need to tumble it to polish down any fibers that are sticking out... which will create more of the microparticles you need to wash away. It may require several rounds of this but eventually you will get roundish polished bone with a density and consistency in the range of some kinds of sand.

Would it be fluid enough to flow in copper tubes and to be used in an hourglass

When you are done, the particles will still be more porous, a lower density, and able to retain more water than most kinds of sand; so it will not flow as well as other sands, but it should be very similar to the pumicite sand you might find near volcanoes.

I like the idea of having one type of sand made out of the bones of magical creatures and its true composition being a big secret, but I am not sure it would work.

If you label it as some kind of pumicite, you could probably fool the average sand mage, at least for a little while.
All that said, you will not be able to hide the fact that it is bone forever.  You can make it look like sand, feel like sand, and move like sand, but bone has a distinct taste and smell no matter what you do to process it; so, even after you do everything you can to make it look and feel like sand, if someone puts some in their mouth, it will taste suspiciously like like the broth of whatever animal it was made from, then your secrete is out.
The good news though is that most people will have no clue what kind of bone it is made from.  Unless it is from a common livestock animal like cows, pigs, or chickens, most people will not be able to discern what dragon or phoenix bone tastes like.  So even if a few mages taste it, they will know it has a bone-like taste, but not necessarily be able to narrow it down enough to reproduce it.

This answer directly addresses the "flowing through an hourglass" requirement of the question, which is an issue of particle shape and size, not weight. Tiny grains of beach sand are no heavier than flakes of ash or sawdust. Flow requires smooth rigid ovals or spheres that are likely to slip past each other instead of stacking or binding. Those shapes are produced both naturally and artificially by a combination of drying, grinding, and tumbling actions. You'll also want to sieve and filter to get batches of similar-sized particles, which flow much better than mixes.

Thanks!!!
The technical limitations of bone-sand fit the story quite nicely. I can make it a rule of  engineering that all magic sands are to never be exposed to open air, and only be in contact with dry gases inside the machines' pipes. So humidity won't be a problem, and people would only be in position to smell ou touch bone-sand in accidental circumstances.
Its production being a long and complicated process is perfectly fine too

@JayMcEh Weight does matter.  Sand has to overcome friction to flow, being smooth reduces its friction, yes, but its weight determines how much force each particle has for overcoming that friction.  So if you have two sands with identical particle size and surface geometry, but one is more dense than the other, the more dense one will flow under gravity better.

I want to clarify something to satiate my own curiosity. Is this referring to raw bones or roasted bones, and how would bonemeal of the two differ? I assume bonemeal made from roasted bones would have lost nearly all of the protein composition (leaving not much besides just carbon) and the hydroxyapatite would have decomposed into something else entirely.

@Abion47 Raw bones, though low temperature roasting just to speed up the drying should be very similar.  When burned at temperatures that are high enough to do what you describe, the bones become calcined, but IMO, at that point  what you have left is no more bone than ash is wood.  I feel like that would be a different question.

note it will not fool anyone who actually knows anythign about sand and looks at it, bone is very soft, very reactive compared to silica sand. An acid test, a fairly common test for identifying rock, will immediatly identify it as calcium based.  you also have the issue that is will disolve in acidic rain very quickly if it is present. because it is soft it will make for horrible hourglasses, since it will quickly break into finer particles. If you want to remove the smell you can bleach bone, which will still taste funny but will not smell.

@John It will not be mistaken for silica sand,no. but the OP stipulates that "artificers use various types of sand as components for their magitek contraptions."  Which means that it only needs to pass as some kind of sand, not a specific sand.  Aragonite sand for example is even more alkaline and softer than bone, and yes, it is rich in calcium, but it is still a mineral sand; so, the bone sand could still fall into the expected range of exotic sands that these artificers are used to using.

@Nosajimiki I missed that stipulation, yeah bone sand could easily pass for argonite sand to any but the most specialized geology student. there is even sand made from normal bone its just ussually mixed in with shell sand.

You can use mortar and pestle to grind pieces of bone into any size from small sharp pieces to rounded sand grains to fine powder.
Given enough time and erosion by wind, water and sun those levels of granularity can also be achieved in natural ways.
What you probably want to have is fully dried, mineralized bone.
Fresh bone has all sorts of living tissues to it and will start to rot soon if just left alone.
Drying takes quite some time under the sun and needs to have a way to get rid of all the tissue and pieces of flesh, nerves etc. - for example by ants, maggots and others.
Fully dried bone powder or grains probably dissolve/mix (not clump) in water since they are essentially made of salts.
As for the odor I cannot give you a definitive answer. Bone meal is used as fertilizer and animal food though, maybe you get an idea about it from that area.

Thanks for your answer ! I just looked for bone meal online and garden stores actually sell it in small quantities (the size of a regular food can). I'm probabably going to buy one and see what bonemeal looks like directly

"Bone powder or grains probably dissolve in water since they are essentially made of salts" .. Bone, is mostly calcium, we have cliffs made of the stuff, and some really big regions filled with hills of the stuff, we call them chalk downs, we're also known for our soggy weather with plentiful rainfall.. Hi from the UK by the way ;) .. they've all been there rather a long time, apparently nobody told them they should have dissolved and washed away by now, I'll just go let them know shall I? ;) .. but I'm no chemist, may have to check the properties of calcium carbonate v calcium phosphate

@Pelinore Actually, they are only about 20% calcium, that calcium is stored in a mineral salt called hydroxyapatite: Ca10(PO4)6(OH)2.  As far as salts go, hydroxyapatite is minimally water soluble.  That said, 30-35% of bone mass is other organic compounds like proteins and stuff.  So, while bone can decompose into chalk over very long periods of time.  Bone meal has very different characteristics because of all the other stuff in it.

@Pelinore I'd say the cliffs of Dover are still there because there is so much chalk - literally mountains of it. It shows clear signs of erosion though. According to wikipedia it loses about 20cm a year recently and is estimated to last for tens of thousands of years still.

@Antares One would imagine that were it being dissolved as a salt by water as the primary active cause of erosion that you might have a somewhat more substantial rate of erosion than a mere 20cm a year, 20m a year would be rather less than one might expect by several orders of magnitude for a sea adjacent cliff composed of table salt or sugar, I'm not really sure you've convinced me

@Pelinore Salts generally make really bad sand (as soon as it get's moist) though. Your chalk cliffs don't really have beaches (with a sand vibe), so they?

@Pelinore: well, seawater is saturated with salts and stuff already maybe therefore it is less eroding.

@Antares I think Nosajimiki probably had your answer up there > "as salts go .. it's minimally water soluble" .. that 20cm is just what might be expected from mechanical erosion by wind and wave for a 'rock' this soft, probably .. and chalk tends to break down into a powder rather than granules so that would be Hobbamoks answer I suspect, gets washed off the beaches in suspension rather than solution or just sifts down through the beach stones perhaps .. but if it was very soluble I just have a feeling we should be seeing a lot more erosion than 20cm a year, just doesn't seem enough.

It should be possible to chemically remove collagen from the crushed bone, but unfortunately the opposite is so commonly done IRL that a quick search (all I have time for) doesn't find a method

Yes and No
What is sand?

Sand is a granular material composed of finely divided mineral particles. Sand has various compositions but is defined by its grain size. Sand grains are smaller than gravel and coarser than silt. Sand can also refer to a textural class of soil or soil type; i.e., a soil containing more than 85 percent sand-sized particles by mass.
The composition of sand varies, depending on the local rock sources and conditions, but the most common constituent of sand in inland continental settings and non-tropical coastal settings is silica (silicon dioxide, or SiO2), usually in the form of quartz.
Calcium carbonate is the second most common type of sand. One such example of this is aragonite, which has been created over the past 500 million years by various forms of life, such as coral and shellfish. It is the primary form of sand apparent in areas where reefs have dominated the ecosystem for millions of years, as in the Caribbean. Somewhat more rarely, sand may be composed of calcium sulfate, such as gypsum and selenite, as is found in places such as White Sands National Park and Salt Plains National Wildlife Refuge in the U.S. (Source)

So when other answers suggest that sand can come from creatures, it's a little misleading. It comes from the minerals of those creatures, like calcium carbonate (shells). Not just anything, and this is important. From that same source we read...

Sand is a non-renewable resource over human timescales, and sand suitable for making concrete is in high demand. Desert sand, although plentiful, is not suitable for concrete. Fifty billion tons of beach sand and fossil sand are used each year for construction.

In other words, all sand is not created equal. For example, whatever "sand" you can get from bone isn't suitable for creating integrated circuits, which specifically depends on silica.
Anything solid can be ground up into particles the size of sand. But does that make the result "sand?" The word is applied to a great many things and they're not all equal and they're not all interchangeable.
Which is a really long and fancy way of saying, "it works if the application you're thinking about is appropriate for it, and it doesn't work if it's not."

Ground up silica is great for integrated circuits. Ground up bone is not.
Ground up granite, gneiss and limestone is great for concrete. Ground up bone is not.
Ground up silicon carbide is great for polishing rocks. Ground up bone is not.
Ground up aluminum oxide is great for sandpaper. Ground up bone is not.
Ground up calcium carbonate is great for antacid. Bone might be good for this, too... if prepared properly, because (for example) bone dust when breathed into the lungs can lead to Hepatitis B and C, Streptococci, and Human Immunodeficiency Virus (HIV).

So... yes and no.
On the whole and from a science perspective I'd vote no, bone sand would not behave like other sands. But it really depends on the application. In your case, where you're bringing magic into the mix, the answer is certainly yes. Thanks to the magic, bone sand would act like any other kind of sand due to narrative necessity. So if the question is, "would this be believable in the context of my world?" the answer is "oh, yeah!"

Yes I'm only interested in the aspect and fluidity of the bone-sand itself, not of the materials that are made from sand. Thank you for your last comment! I was worried about making the twist believable :)


Would bone-sand behave like regular sand?

Yes, regular sand is made of many different substances. They all behave the same way when nature makes them into sand grains. Some is made by parrot fish, some is pulverised rock from rivers, but at the end of the day they're much the same.

On the other hand, almost all natural sand is mostly silica...

Thank you!! I didn't know about parrotfish. And I didn't know there already are beaches made of coral "bones" sand either.  I'll probably accept your answer in a little while, I'll just wait a bit to see if someone else has something interesting to answer

It sounds like a good idea. Magical sands or powders have many uses.
The difference between "sand", which is usually silicon dioxide, and bone, which is usually based on calcium, is unimportant. What is important is that the sand-powder is derived from the bones of magical creatures.
The bones can be whole or ground to any size of particle, depending on how they will be used. Certainly the sand-powder can be used in an hourglass mechanism. It can be used inside a tube as part of your alchemy. There are no limitations except those you might invent. The "magic dust" or powder is an old trope; even Cheech and Chong used it in one of their comedy routines.
"...[T]he King turned him away and, taking from a shelf a retort filled with a dark blue fluid, set it on a bain-marie, and a lamp thereunder. Fumes of a faint purple hue came forth from the neck of the retort, and the King gathered them in a flask. He made signs over the flask and shook forth into his hand therefrom a fine powder." -- E. R. Eddison, "The Worm Ouroboros", Chapter IV, "Conjuring in the Iron Tower"
Now, whence came this "dark blue fluid"? Your powder of magical bones can be transformed to a stable solution and stored as the first step of the magical operation. Then it can used as needed. Use your imagination.
